# How to close/hide some container

Tags: flutter

i want to close some container after clicking a close button but i dont know how to do that,
i'm already try using if-else but i'm on stuck now maybe anyone can help to fix it

> here my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../theme.dart';

class PencapaianBersama_Section extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isTap;
  const PencapaianBersama_Section({
    Key? key,
    this.isTap = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isTap) {
      return SizedBox();
    } else {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
        height: 148,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: whiteColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Pencapaian bersama',
                          style: grayText.copyWith(fontSize: 10),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Periode Agustus 2022',
                          style: blackText.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 8,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 25,
                              height: 24,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage(
                                      'assets/images/proses/icon_recycle.png'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 8,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '16%',
                              style: blackText.copyWith(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: semiBold),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 8,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Penurunan dari periode sebelumnya',
                          style: grayText.copyWith(fontSize: 8),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 8,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Selengkapnya',
                          style: lightBlueText.copyWith(fontSize: 10),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 149,
                      height: 92,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(
                                'assets/images/proses/image_pencapaian.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Spacer(),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (() {
                    isTap == !isTap;
                  }),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 16,
                    height: 16,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image:
                            AssetImage('assets/images/proses/icon_close.png'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

it's some illustration the program that i want to make, from picture on left to the right
[here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rK6T.png)
can someone help me about it, i'm new on coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**here** is how you can do it using **stateful widget.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../theme.dart';

class PencapaianBersama_Section extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isTap;
  PencapaianBersama_Section({
    Key? key,
    this.isTap = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PencapaianBersama_Section> createState() => _PencapaianBersama_SectionState();
}

class _PencapaianBersama_SectionState extends State<PencapaianBersama_Section> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.isTap) {
      return SizedBox();
    } else {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          widget.isTap = !widget.isTap;
          setState((){});
        },
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
          height: 148,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: whiteColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Pencapaian bersama',
                            style: grayText.copyWith(fontSize: 10),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Periode Agustus 2022',
                            style: blackText.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 8,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 25,
                                height: 24,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage(
                                        'assets/images/proses/icon_recycle.png'),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 8,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '16%',
                                style: blackText.copyWith(
                                    fontSize: 20, fontWeight: semiBold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 8,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Penurunan dari periode sebelumnya',
                            style: grayText.copyWith(fontSize: 8),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 8,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Selengkapnya',
                            style: lightBlueText.copyWith(fontSize: 10),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 149,
                        height: 92,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/proses/image_pencapaian.png'),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Spacer(),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (() {
                      widget.isTap == !widget.isTap;
                    }),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 16,
                      height: 16,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image:
                          AssetImage('assets/images/proses/icon_close.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the widget to statefull widget. and change the ontap method like bellow

```
onTap: (() {
  setState((){
    isTap == !isTap;
  });
  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

int onTap method set isTap into SetState,

```
  setState((){
           isTap == !isTap;
    });
```

& do this in tour buildcontext method

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isTap ? SizedBox(height:0) :
       
          Container(
```